# exporting a certain worksheet from a workbook to pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

i am an amateur programmer learning how to program using vba

without further a due, my question is :

i have created a listbox (listbox1) where i've listed all my sheets(ws) name in a specific workbook.
i've also created another listbox(listbox2) where when i select some  sheets name on the listbox1, they will be transfer to listbox2.

my main objective is that by choosing  one or more sheets listed in the listbox2, and by clicking a button, i'll manage to save all the selected sheets in one pdf file.

here is the code for the button used to export the file in pdf that i've written but i've only managed to export them not in one pdf file but in numerous amount of pdf file.

```
Dim NomTableau() As String

For Each WkbkName In application.Workbooks()    
If WkbkName.Name = choix_poteau.Value & "_" & section & "_" & projet & ".xlsx" Then
WkbkName.Activate
GoTo lois
End If    
Next

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(add1 & "\" & Me.projet.Value & "\" & Me.section.Value & "\poteaux\" & Me.choix_poteau.Value & "_" & Me.section & "_" & Me.projet & ".xlsx")

lois:

For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
While ListBox2.List(i) <> ""
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Name = ListBox2.List(i) Then

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\Export\Resultats__" & ListBox2.List(i - counter) & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True

End If

Next
Wend

Next i
End Sub
```

thanks alot, really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of exporting each sheet individually, select them all first and then call the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method.

Here is my test code, which worked as expected:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestPDF()

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim arrSheets() As String
        Dim strSheets As String

        'Get our sheet names
        For i = 1 To 3
                strSheets = Worksheets(i).Name & "," & strSheets
        Next

        'Trim the trailing comma
        strSheets = Left(strSheets, Len(strSheets) - 1)

        arrSheets = Split(strSheets, ",")

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arrSheets).Select

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\qzbcjs\Documents\Useful Workbooks\test.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True

End Sub
```

I declared an array of strings, populated a string variable with the comma-delimited names of the worksheets (in my case I just wanted the first through third sheets), split that comma-delimited string into an array and used the array to select all of the desired sheets and only called the `ExportAsFixedFormat` method once.

Adapting this method to your code, beginning as the `lois` part would look something like this:

```
lois:

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim arrSheets() As String
        Dim strWs As String

        For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
                While ListBox2.List(i) <> ""

                        For Each ws In Worksheets
                                If ws.Name = ListBox2.List(i) Then
                                        strWs = ws.Name & "," & strWs
                                End If
                        Next
                Wend
        Next i

        strWs = Left(strWs, Len(strWs) - 1)

        arrSheets = Split(strWs, ",")

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arrSheets).Select

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Export\Resultats__" & ListBox2.List(i - counter) & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True
```